# how to count how many words when using a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am joining 2 tables like :

```
    RIGHT JOIN Sheet.dbo.tbl_M_Tam TD  ON TD.Name = EU.Name
```

The problem is that sometimes EU.Name is like 'name1' and TD is 'name1 KO' in this case the join won't work. So I want to make it work by adding the string 'KO' in EU.Name when it is a one word string.

Is there is a simple way to do that, I am using SQL Server ?

Comment: Does this apply to this specific strings or are there more variations?

Comment: It applies on ly to his specific string

Comment: Redesign your database. "KO" seems to be a good candidate for a yes/no (boolean) flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is just for the one specific string ('KO') then this should work.

```
RIGHT JOIN Sheet.dbo.tbl_M_Tam TD  
    ON TD.Name = CASE WHEN EU.Name LIKE '% %' THEN EU.Name ELSE EU.Name + ' KO' END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  RIGHT JOIN Sheet.dbo.tbl_M_Tam TD  ON TD.Name LIKE EU.Name +'%'
```

But be warned that this is not the most efficient way of doing a `JOIN` on many rows in a system with high ussage.
If you want to be efficient try to clean up your data in some way so that you can do a straight col1 equals col2 join.

Answer (score 1):

```
RIGHT JOIN Sheet.dbo.tbl_M_Tam TD 
ON TD.Name = EU.Name OR TD.Name = Eu.Name + ' KO'
```

An example created on how it would work.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87e081/2

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but it's not going to be fast:

```
RIGHT JOIN Sheet.dbo.tbl_M_Tam TD  ON 
  CASE when charindex(' ', TD.Name) = 0 then td.name + ' KO' else td.name end = EU.Name
```

The case statement is evaluated, if a space does not exist then 'KO is added otherwise the original column value is used.